# How to make incoming call in Genymotion emulator for Android?

Tags: android, genymotion, phone-call

How can I make an incoming call in [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) emulator for Android?

I am using Genymotion emulator to run and test my application.

In the native emulator DDMS, we can make a fake call. Can this be done using the Genymotion emulator?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the call function in Genymotion...

The *Phone* widget allows to test applications relying on telephony features and observe their behavior when receiving a call or a text message.

[image]

To use the Phone widget, click  or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>.
**To simulate an incoming call:**

1. Enter an incoming phone number.
2. Click Call.

**To simulate an incoming message:**

1.Enter an incoming phone number.
 2.Enter a text message.
 3.Click Send message.

The text message is displayed in the virtual device via a notification and can also be read in the Messaging application.

:( This feature is only available with Indie and Business licenses.

Comment: Consider changing your accepted answer to this answer if you want, since this is the latest information.

Comment: FYI you can also launch phone calls from instrumented tests code using the Java API: https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/java-api

Comment: in window 7 when i press ctrl+8 its open google search not able to get above view.

Answer (score 28):

There is no way to do that in Genymotion yet.

**UPDATE:**

Since version 2.4.0 Genymotion supports phone ans SMS emulation.
You can control it from the UI, using the dedicated widget or [the Java API](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/java-api) to launch it from your Java instrumented tests code.

Disclaimer: I work for Genymotion.

Comment: any idea when this feature will be available? Great work so far on geny!

Comment: I suppose it is safe to assume there is also no way to simulate a mobile data network? If so, please let us know.

Comment: *UPDATE* : Now you can place a call or send SMS in Genymotion's latest update. Unfortunately, works only with the purchased version only. https://www.genymotion.com/#!/pricing

Answer (score 3):

It is not implemented yet, but for testing purposes give 911 in your number field. This will take you to the dialer without throwing `Mobile network not available`.

You can also try `911856`, `911782222`, `911666666`, etc. 
**As long as it starts with 911 this would suffice for testing purposes!!!**