# Install Samsung apps in Genymotion

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, genymotion

How to install Samsung app store in Genymotion?
I want to test in-app service of Samsung in Genymotion.
I have installed Samsung app store but it required a sim card.

**The Error is:**

> No SIM card. Unable to launch application.

Comment: Have you tried adding an sd card?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530114/accessing-files-from-genymotion-sd-card

Comment: @eduyayo The error is: "No SIM card. Unable to launch application".

Comment: but this guy works for genymotion and says it is not possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198871/how-to-make-incoming-call-in-genymotion-emulator-in-android

Comment: @eduyayo It is possible now in new Genymotion update. My question is regarding Samsung IAP.  How can I make it work?

Comment: In the last release we included SIM card emulation (phone & SMS). It is limited to paid clients if you own a business or indie license you should definitly try out with a newly created device.

Comment: @eyal-lezmy That's nice feature, but I use free version. Is it possible to add Samsung apps (samsung store, In-App billing, camera, etc.) in Genymotion?

Comment: You can add any app you want. The problem is that it checks the hardware compatibility. The device behaves like it does not have a SIM card and your in-app billing process requires a SIM card. So it is not compatible with the device in this configuration.

Comment: For the store I would not be surprised it needs to be installed on a TouchWizz device. We don't support TouchWizz today as it is not open source (we need the source code to build a device). For the camera, there could be hardware problem but maybe not, just test it.

Comment: @eyal-lezmy I have changed model and manufacture in build.prop. And then install flashable apps to Genymotion but then the device does not start. Thanks for the reply, I don't think it will work.